# Read xpath from another xml in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml document which stores the xpath

```
<Field col_header="Content ID " mapping="$contentTagRef/v41:contentId" />
<Field col_header="Channel (Mandatory)" mapping="v43:channelId" />
<Field col_header="HID (Mandatory)" mapping="v43:eventId" />
<Field col_header="TX Date (Mandatory)" mapping="$eventTimeStamp" />    
<Field col_header="TX Date (Mandatory)" mapping="$eventTimeStamp" />
```

I have a xsl where i need to iterate over these fields on my matched item and retrieve the values.

```
<!-- Reading the other document as -->
<xsl:param name="mappingsFile" select="document('SVT_input_Mappings.xml')" />
<xsl:template match="v43:event">

    <xsl:param name="contentTagRef"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="materialTagRef"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="eventTimeStamp"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:variable name="root">
        <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:for-each select="$mappingsFile//Field">

        <xsl:variable name="mapping">
            <xsl:value-of select="@mapping"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:variable>

        -- How to evaluate the mapping ?? -----
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Output I am getting as

```
 $contentTagRef/v41:contentId
```

instead i m expecting as

```
Content1-xx-454
```

Comment: This is not possible with XSLT 1.0's built-in functionality. What XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: Oh Ok , I am using 1.0.  Any suggestions on how to achieve this ?

Comment: You didn't answer my question. What XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: @JLRishe XSLT 1.0 SAXON

Comment: Which version of Saxon? (And why not the latest, which supports XSLT 2.0 and 3.0?) Anyway, Saxon supports `evaluate()` as an extension - look at the product's documentation.

Comment: P.S. Please add the second XML to your question.